# Image multiple tap zooming

Tags: iphone

Can anyone please suggest me a good sample code for multiple tap zooming image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's [ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) sample contains example of zooming on response to taps (it seems it was updated to use `UIGestureRecognizer` to handle touches so if you're targeting iOS 3.x you'll need to find the older version of that sample).

Comment: Thanks vlad.
We are using UIGestureRecognizer actually. It doesn't throw any error in simulator but crashes when installed on the iphone device. Any idea on what could be wrong with this?Also I would appreciate if you could send me the URL where I can find the older versions sample.

Comment: Hi Vlad, the present version on the site is 1.2 and i got access to 1.1 infact. The one that i have implemented already is 1.1 and its crashing when installed on the iphone with OS4.0. Any thoughts on what could be wrong? it works fine in simulator.

Comment: Have you checked crash log and console messages on crash? I don't have device with iOS4 now, but sample runs ok on 3.1

Comment: Can u please give me the sample code that works fine on 3.1...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its just apple's sample, version 1.1. What errors do you get?